# How to save statistical parameters of a raster stack in a csv using R

Tags: raster, r, stack

I have a reference raster and a stack of other rasters. I wanted to perform Mean, Std Dev and Bias of the reference with respect to the remaining. So I calculated the Cell Stats of all but when I try to save it in a csv its shows me columns more than the number of stack rasters.The no of rows is the exeact number of columns while the in the next column it doubles up and so on. The values of mean and all is a num while in the stack rasters its shows as named num. [image]

The code is as shown:

```
r1 <- raster("Ref.tif")
mn<-cellStats(r1, stat='mean', na.rm=TRUE, asSample=TRUE)
 sdev<-cellStats(r1, stat='sd', na.rm=TRUE, asSample=TRUE)
 min_V<-minValue(r1)
max_V<-maxValue(r1)
lt <- list.files(pattern = "\\.tif$")
st <- stack(lt)
st<-resample(st,r1)
mn1<-as.numeric(cellStats(st, stat='mean', na.rm=TRUE, asSample=TRUE))
sdev1<-as.numeric(cellStats(st, stat='sd', na.rm=TRUE, asSample=TRUE))
min_V1<-as.numeric(minValue(st))
max_V1<-as.numeric(maxValue(st))
bias_mn<-as.numeric(mn-mn1)
bias_mn2<-as.numeric(bias_mn^2)
tab <- table(min_V1,max_V1, bias_mn, bias_mn2) 
write.csv(tab, file="Out.csv")
```

Comment: Your `table` call is tabulating all your data so you ar egetting a frequency count of the occurrences of each set of values. Did you really mean to make a data frame instead of a table?

Comment: I just want to export it in a csv. I am not so familiar with a data frame

Comment: Do you  know what `table` does? Why did you use it here?

Comment: Can you add it as an answer?